# Google Places API vs Google Maps location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Whenever I press different buildings on Google Maps, I'm getting the building names. I would expect these to also be given by Google Places if I give the appropriate latitude and longitude parameters. While the Google Places API does supply me with a lot of data, it usually don't have the building for which the google Maps displays.

Why is there this discrepancy? Am I using the wrong API to get building names based on lat, long coords?

**EDIT:** By examining the logs, I found a call that retrieves Lechner Residence Hall, though I don't know if this is accessible via API.

The call: https://www.google.com/maps/preview/reveal?authuser=0&hl=en&pb=!2m9!1m3!1d771.2274427635097!2d-96.3441961!3d30.6159525!2m0!3m2!1i533!2i690!4f13.1!3m2!2d-96.34387557602872!3d30.616141781213884!4m2!1sEYD3VI7BDMeqNu7Xg_AP!7e81!5m12!1e1!1e2!1e5!1e3!1e10!1e12!1e15!2m3!1i88!2i60!3i1!4smaps_sv.tactile

It seems like you can see the coords in the string: -96.3438755760 and 30.6161417812.

**Example:**

[image]

Notice how my pointer is on a building, and that building is Lechner Residence Hall. The coodinates are 30.616204, -96.343964.

Via the Google Places API, I get `["Houston St", "College Station"]`

Why is this? I am using a Radius of 25 meters by the way.

Comment: Where does it say they will be the same?

Comment: Perhaps it was a bad assumption on my part, but I felt Google Places would give you the building name associated with the coordinates.

Comment: For the `Google Places API`, it has `Place Details`, which included more info, please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details)

Comment: @bjiang Place Details requires the `place_id`, whereas I'm hoping to Derive `Lechner Residence Hall` via the lat, long. I am using coordinates inside the building, but it isn't being brought up in the Places search.